# How to display alert after deleting column

Tags: javascript

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once'database.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
//echo $id;
$sql="DELETE FROM housingtable WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result)
    {
        echo "Deleted Successfully";

        echo "<br>";
        //echo "<a href='avayatable.php'> Back to main page </a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR!";
        // close connection 
        mysql_close();
    }
header("location:viewproperty.php");
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
    ?>
```

> unable to display alert box once i delete the record from
>   database.please check my code above.unable to display alert box once i delete the record from database.please check my code above.

Comment: Because you're redirecting the user.  Once the browser sees the redirect header, it follows the redirect.  It doesn't also display the page.

Comment: can u help me how to display alert..after alert box it should redirect to other page

Comment: As I see you did not accept the given answer. Do you still need advice on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent");';
echo 'location.href="viewproperty.php";';
echo '</script>';
```

This will work.

Comment: This has the exact same problem as the original code.  A redirect *header* tells the browser not to render anything, but to redirect the user instead.  In many cases this would even produce an error, because unless buffering output PHP won't allow you to change headers after emitting output.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display the alert first and then redirect, you could perform the redirect in your client-side code.  Something like this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent");';
echo 'window.location.replace("viewproperty.php");';
echo '</script>';
```

As a suggestion for user experience, you might try displaying a friendly message (not an `alert()`) in the HTML of the `viewproperty.php` page instead.  Include some indicator, perhaps on the URL or in the session, that the message should be displayed.  Then in that page include some HTML for displaying that friendly message.